# "Double-ended" hyper-ref macro: how to make it as automatic as possible?

Tags: macros, hyperref

In general, a reference to a particular object can appear multiple times in a document. So, one cannot infer which reference brought us to the referred object.

But what if a reference is guaranteed to only appear once? In such a case, one can imagine a double-ended hyperlink: clicking on the link will take you to the other end, and click on the other end, will take you back to the original position.

Here is a manual implementation of a double-ended hyperlink:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{alpha}{\hyperlink{beta}{soft}} 

kitty, 

warm 

kitty, 

little 

ball 

of 

fur! 

Happy 

kitty, 

sleepy 

kitty, 

purr 

purr 

\hypertarget{beta}{\hyperlink{alpha}{purr!}}  

\end{document}
```

It would be nice to wrap the manual implementation into as automagic a macro as possible. A simple macro implementation is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\dehref}[4]{%
    \IfEqCase{#3}{%
        {1}{\hypertarget{#1}{\hyperlink{#2}{#4}}}%
        {2}{\hypertarget{#2}{\hyperlink{#1}{#4}}}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\dehref{alpha}{beta}{1}{soft}

kitty, 

warm 

kitty, 

little 

ball 

of 

fur! 

Happy 

kitty, 

sleepy 

kitty, 

purr 

purr 

\dehref{alpha}{beta}{2}{purr!}

\end{document}
```

But it has several drawbacks:

- no relevant errors will be raised if we re-use labels
- user has to remember 1/2 to indicate "direction" of the hyperlink
- 4 arguments needed!

Any ideas on how one can simplify such a macro?

Comment: Have you looked at the code for `hyperindex` and `backref`?

Comment: @cfr no, let me look into that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variant uses one label for both ends, and uses `\@ifundefined` to determine whether this is the first or second occurrence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\backlink}[2]% #1 = label, #2 = text
{\@ifundefined{back@#1}%
  {\expandafter\xdef\csname back@#1\endcsname{1}%
    \hypertarget{back@#1}{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}}%
  {\ifnum\csname back@#1\endcsname>1
    \errmessage{backlink #1 already used twice.}%
  \else
    \expandafter\xdef\csname back@#1\endcsname{2}%
    \hypertarget{#1}{\hyperlink{back@#1}{#2}}%
  \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\backlink{alpha}{soft}

kitty, 

warm 

kitty, 

little 

ball 

of 

fur! 

Happy 

kitty, 

sleepy 

kitty, 

purr 

purr 

\backlink{alpha}{purr!}

\end{document}
```